# Javascript division

Tags: javascript, operations

In my console browser, I put:

> 666.66/10

And I get:

> 66.666

(As expected). But when I put:

> 6666.66/10

I get:

> 666.6659999999999

Can someone explain me why this happen? It shouldn't be: 666.666 ?

Comment: Its due to floating point

See this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458633/elegant-workaround-for-javascript-floating-point-number-problem

Comment: Because JS sucks? Well, maybe that doesn't help, but probably something to do with floating point math.

Comment: I think this question has been asked enough.

Answer (score 2):

Computers don't store numbers in base 10, like we think - it's in base 2, so oddities like the one you've found are common.

Another one is `0.1 + 0.2`, which counter intuitively equals `0.30000000000000004`

If you want to safely divide numbers, either convert them to whole numbers first or use a library like [BigDecimal](https://github.com/dtrebbien/BigDecimal.js)